# HP Zbook G5 with Apple Thunderbolt Display

Tags: display, apple, thunderbolt

I am running an HP Zbook 15 G5 at work and am working on transitioning from using the new Macbooks with Touchbar to this with Ubuntu 18.04.3 with HWE packages installed.
When connecting this machine to an Apple Cinema Display (27") using the Apple-Thunderbolt-2-to-USB-C adapter sold by them, it seems the monitor only works on waking from sleep, with an incorrect resolution. Otherwise, when I hotplug it while the laptop is on, or keep it plugged in while powering on, it does not work.

Things I have tried:

- Disable Thunderbolt Preboot ACL in BIOS settings and enable
- Native mode + low-power for Thunderbolt in BIOS
- Legacy mode for Thunderbolt in BIOS
- reset BIOS to factory defaults, then re-enable legacy boot as our install requires

Here is the output from journalctl --follow when unplugging and replugging the display:

```
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-12-17 11:50:53 PST. --
Dec 17 17:50:28 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Dec 17 17:50:28 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) event25 - FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Dec 17 17:50:28 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) event25 - FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: device is a keyboard
Dec 17 17:52:30 aseibenick-ltl7 pkexec[5158]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1267257390)
Dec 17 17:52:30 aseibenick-ltl7 pkexec[5165]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1267257390)
Dec 17 17:52:31 aseibenick-ltl7 pkexec[5171]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1267257390)
Dec 17 17:52:31 aseibenick-ltl7 pkexec[5177]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1267257390)
Dec 17 17:52:31 aseibenick-ltl7 pkexec[5183]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1267257390)
Dec 17 17:52:31 aseibenick-ltl7 pkexec[5189]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1267257390)
Dec 17 17:52:41 aseibenick-ltl7 firefox.desktop[4210]: [Parent 4210, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (150): Connection reset by peer: file /build/firefox-AWfb_V/firefox-71.0+build5/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
Dec 17 17:56:52 aseibenick-ltl7 gsd-media-keys[3339]: Unable to get default sink
Dec 17 17:56:52 aseibenick-ltl7 gsd-media-keys[3339]: Unable to get default source
Dec 17 17:56:52 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) config/udev: removing device FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F
Dec 17 17:56:52 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (**) Option "fd" "71"
Dec 17 17:56:52 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) event25 - FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: device removed
Dec 17 17:56:52 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Dec 17 17:56:52 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:89
Dec 17 17:56:52 aseibenick-ltl7 gnome-shell[3167]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Apple Inc. Display Audio (/dev/input/event24)
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 gsd-media-keys[3339]: Unable to get default source
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F (/dev/input/event25)
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (**) FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F'
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event25 13:89 fd 71 paused 0
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (**) FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: always reports core events
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event25"
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) event25 - FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) event25 - FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: device is a keyboard
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) event25 - FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: device removed
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:04.0/0000:3c:00.0/0000:3d:00.0/0000:3e:00.0/0000:3f:03.0/0000:40:00.2/usb7/7-1/7-1.5/7-1.5:1.0/input/input50/event25"
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F" (type: KEYBOARD, id 18)
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) event25 - FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Dec 17 17:57:03 aseibenick-ltl7 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3018]: (II) event25 - FaceTime HD Camera (Display): F: device is a keyboard
^C
```